# Possible to change where Android Virtual Devices are saved?

Tags: windows, android, android-virtual-device

I've set up the Android SDK and Eclipse on my machine running Windows XP and AVDs (Android Virtual Devices) are saved to "Documents and Settings\*user*\.android" by default.  Is there any way to change this behavior?  I have all of the other components saved in a directory on a separate partition and would like everything to be consolidated.  Obviously not a huge deal but does anyone here know a workaround for this?

Comment: I have made virtual RAM disk which is 100x faster than SSD and moving emulator files to this disk speed ups emulator loading very much.

Comment: @Vinigas Can you elaborate please " RAM disk which is 100x " I want to speed up my emulator too

Comment: I use "SoftPerfect RAM disk" software to create virtual disk. Then I put android emulator files into this RAM-disk and setting emulator location. If you have HDD, then you will see big difference between emulator in HDD and  in RAM.

Comment: Save question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109473/moving-default-avd-configuration-folder-android#

Comment: In 2021 this should be a couple of clicks.  Why are things made so complicated?

Comment: @Kenny still not easy to do in Android Studio in 2022 sigh.

Answer (score 343, accepted):

Add a new user environment variable (Windows 7):

1. Start Menu > Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings (on the left) > Environment Variables
2. Add a new user variable (at the top) that points your home user directory:

> Variable name: **ANDROID_SDK_HOME**
>  Variable value:
>   *a path to a directory of your choice*

AVD Manager will use this directory to save its `.android` directory into it.

For those who may be interested, I blogged about my first foray into Android development...
[Android "Hello World": a Tale of Woe](http://wloescher.blogspot.com/2011/01/android-hello-world-tale-of-woe.html)

Alternatively, you can use the [Rapid Environment Editor](https://www.rapidee.com/en/download) to set the environment variables.

Comment: This should actually be the accepted answer. Straight forward and concise. Thank you wloescher.

Comment: Thanks. Reading your blog entry was like reliving the first few hours of today mucking about with this. What a pain!

Comment: +1 for your info. but I am using xp. for me this will work after restart. Thank you.

Comment: +100000000000000 You saved my life. I changed many times the value without effect (C:/Android, C:/Android/android-sdk, C:/users, ...), I have just to desinstall W8, but finally it seems work with you value as user variable and not as system variable as i was trying (i do not if this matter but it is working not). Thank you.

Comment: This also worked with Android Studio, which kept on creating a `.android` folder at the root of my workspace partition. I was finally able to put it in my home folder in Windows using this method.

Comment: This isn't the answer that works. And it doesn't even seem to answer the question. Next answer by loftysnake did work for me.

Comment: @AlexanderK I have modified the answer to remove the misleading information and add a precision about the path. It works but maybe you have to restart your user session.

Comment: This approach works for me until I restart my computer. Win7.

Comment: Or just type in cmd `setx ANDROID_SDK_HOME D:\your\path\here`

Comment: The ANDROID_AVD_HOME environment variable could be preferred to ANDROID_SDK_HOME as it avoids to move any of the user specific config stored in ~/.android so other users/distributions could so use the same AVDs. Worked nicely on Linux Debian.

Comment: Works for me after restart on Windows 8.1.

Comment: The ANDROID_AVD_HOME solution provided by John is clearest than changing all skd home, in my case, I previously change ANDROID_HOME, the wich changes SDK home but not AVD home, so I had to change AVD manually to some other folder

Comment: I am confirming the `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` solution, but in general the answer as provided by @wloescher is helpful to understand what is going on in the first place. Now I was able to keep the `.android` location, store the Android SDK to a custom location and store my AVDs in a different custom location.

Comment: To be working, the `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` environment variable has to point to an existing directory, or else the default avd directory will be used.

Comment: Note: Starting with Android Studio 4.2, the ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable is deprecated and has been replaced with ANDROID_PREFS_ROOT.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2022 (on Windows 10), neither `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` or `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` worked for me, even after restarting multiple times. :( The emulator just continues to get created on my C: drive (even though Visual Studio is installed to my D: drive, which is where I set the aforementioned Environment Variables to).

Comment: ...or am I misunderstanding something here?...seems like Visual Studio's Adroid Device Manager downloads the files to create the emulator to the C: drive, unpacks them on the C: drive, but creates the actual emulator on the path I set in the aforementioned Environment Variables?...if so, that sucks, because it's still burning like 10 GB to download and unzip the files on the C: drive. :/

Answer (score 87):

Based on official documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables.html you should change **ANDROID_AVD_HOME** environment var:

> **Emulator Environment Variables**
>
> By default, the emulator stores configuration files under
>   $HOME/.android/ and AVD data under $HOME/.android/avd/. You can
>   override the defaults by setting the following environment variables.
>   The emulator -avd  command searches the avd directory in the
>   order of the values in $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,
>   $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd/, and $HOME/.android/avd/. For emulator
>   environment variable help, type emulator -help-environment at the
>   command line. For information about emulator command-line options, see
>   Control the Emulator from the Command Line.
>
> - **ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME**: Sets the path to the user-specific emulator    configuration directory. The default location is
>     $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/.
> - **ANDROID_AVD_HOME**:  Sets the path to the    directory that contains all AVD-specific files, which mostly consist    of very large
>     disk images. The default location is    $ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME/avd/.
>     You might want to specify a new location    if the default location is
>     low on disk space.

After change or set ANDROID_AVD_HOME you will have to move all content inside **~user/.android/avd/** to your new location and change path into ini file of each emulator, just replace it with your new path

Comment: This should be the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I've had a problem with VSCode not seeing emulators after moving them to d:, because I only set ANDROID_AVD_HOME. Adding ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME on top of that resolved it. Thank you.

Comment: This should be the proper way forward...

Answer (score 40):

Modify the file "virtual_android2.2.ini" in "C:\Documents and Settings{your windows login}.android\avd\":

```
target=android-8
path=E:\android_workspace\avd\virtual_android2.2.avd
```

And move the folder "virtual_android2.2.avd" from "C:\Documents and Settings{your windows login}.android\avd\" into "E:\android_workspace\avd\".

Comment: This worked for me! A bit clunky having to do this for every emulator I create

Comment: After numerous complaints of VS' Android Emulator that there is not enough space to install or to start another virtual device, now everything is going smooth.

Answer (score 27):

Move your `.android` to wherever you want it to.

Then, create a symlink like this:

```
# In your home folder
$ ln -s /path/to/.android/ .
```

This simply tells Linux that whenever the path ~`/.android` is referenced by any application, link it to `/path/to/.android`.

Answer (score 17):

Go to the Android tools directory. Edit the android.bat command file. At about the end of the command file, find a line similar to

```
call %java_exe% -Djava.ext.dirs=%java_ext_dirs% -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="%tools_dir%" -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.workdir="%work_dir%" -jar %jar_path% %*
```

and replace

```
call %java_exe%
```

with

```
call %java_exe% -Duser.home={your_prefer_dir}
```

where {your_prefer_dire} is your preferred directory without braces but add doublequotes,

e.g.

```
call %java_exe% -Duser.home="E:\Program Files (x86)\android-sdk-windows"
```

Comment: This worked for me, while the accepted answer didn't. Also, this actually answers what the OP asked, which was how to change from the user home directory to another AVD directory, not the other way around.

Comment: THIS MUST NOT BE DONE! SDK Manager complains about it and it doesn't find the new folder location... Use ANDROID_SDK_HOME under user environments and restart your computer might help - [.android folder will be created in %android_sdk_home%]

Answer (score 10):

**For Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10**

Copy `C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\.android` folder to (for example) `E:\avd`

Open the environment variables window:

1. Go into Settings and click on System.
2. On the left, click About and select System info at the
   bottom.
3. In the new window, click Advanced system
   settings on the left.
4. Click Environment Variables at
   the bottom of the resulting window.

Add a new variable:

- Variable name: `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`
- Variable value: a path to a directory (e.g `E:\avd`)

Don't include `.android` in the variable value.

Restart Visual Studio.

For change SDK & NDK location go to:

> Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Setting

Answer (score 9):

In Windows 10 I had that problem because My C Drive was getting full and I had needed free Space, AVD folder had 14 gig space so I needed to move that folder to another driver, first answer not work for Me so I tested another way to fix it this problem,
I make a picture for you if you have the same problem, you don't need to move all of the files in .android folder to another drive (this way not work) just move avd folders in ....android\avd to another drive and open .ini files and change avd folder path from that file to the new path.
Like this image:

[image: image help you to see how to change old path to new path]

I hope this works for you.

Note: careful about a separate character before and after the path in ini file that you cannot see,if you remove that character it's not works

Answer (score 7):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/developing/tools/avd.html) out.
using the `android` command to create `avd` you can specify where to place files.

```
-p --path     Location path of the directory where the new AVD will be created
```

Comment: Do you know of any way to do this through the setup utility and set it to default to a particular location?

Comment: Not really. I don't even use windows :(

Comment: Well like I said it's not a big deal, just thought there would be some way to control it more given how modular the whole SDK package is.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The link above is dead (http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/developing/tools/avd.html)

Answer (score 7):

You can change the .ini file for the new AVD:

```
target=android-7
path=C:\Users\username\.android\avd\VIRTUAL_DEVICE_NAME.avd
```

I don't know how to specify where the .ini file should be stored :)

Comment: This works great. The .ini has to stay in the old folder.

Answer (score 4):

The environmental variable `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` can be used to define the directory in which the AVD Manager shall look for AVD INI files and can therefore be used to change the location of the virtual devices;

The default value is `%USERPROFILE%\.android\avd` on Windows (or `~/.android/avd` on Linux).

One can also create a link for the whole directory `%USERPROFILE%\.android` on Windows (or a sym-link for directory `~/.android` on Linux).

When moving AVDs, the `path` entry in AVD INI file needs to be updated accordingly.

Comment: This ANDROID_AVD_HOME environment variable could be preferred to ANDROID_SDK_HOME as it avoids to move any of the user specific config stored in ~/.android because other users/distributions could so use the same AVDs.
On Linux, I exported ANDROID_AVD_HOME in my ~/.profile and it works nicely.

Answer (score 4):

1 - Move AVD to new Folder

2 - start Menu > Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings (on the left) > Environment Variables
Add a new user variable:
Variable name: ANDROID_AVD_HOME
Variable value: a path to a directory of your choice

3 - Change the file .INI Set new folder.

4 - Open Android Studio

WORKS - Windows 2010

MORE INSTRUCTIONS : https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables

Answer (score 3):

Another way to specify ANDROID_SDK_HOME without messing around with environment variables (especially when using ec2) is simply create a shortcut of eclipse and add the following as target

C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "setx ANDROID_SDK_HOME ***YOUR AVD PATH*** /M & ***YOUR ECLIPSE.EXE PATH***"

This will set ANDROID_SDK_HOME as system variable whenever you launch eclipse.

HTH
Paul

Answer (score 3):

In my case, what I concerned about is the C: drive disk space.
So what I did is copy the ".avd" folder(not file) to other drive, and leave the ".ini" file there but change it to point to the moved

Comment: best efficient way..

Answer (score 3):

Please take note of the following : modifying android.bat in the Android tools directory, as suggested in a previous answer, may lead to problems.

If you do so, in order to legitimately have your .android directory located to a non-default location then there may be an inconsistency between the AVDs listed by Android Studio (using "Tools > Android > AVD Manager") and the AVDs listed by sdk command line tool "android avd".

I suppose that Android Studio, with its internal AVD Manager, does not use the android.bat modified path ; it relies on the ANDROID_SDK_HOME variable to locate AVDs.

My own tests have shown that Android tools correctly use the ANDROID_SDK_HOME variable.

Therefore, there is no point, as far as I know, in modifying android.bat, and using the environment variable should be preferred.

Answer (score 3):

there are major 4 steps
1. copy the .android folder to your desired location as i did in `D:\Android\.android`
2. set ANDROID_AVD_HOME in environment variables like `ANDROID_AVD_HOME` `D:\Android\.android\avd`
3. change avd name.ini file contents with new location like 
`avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
path=D:\Android\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd
path.rel=avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd
target=android-29`
4. restart android studio

Comment: Modifying the `.ini` file turned out to be an essential step for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to move the **avd** folder from **C:\Users[USER].android folder** to your desired location then create a symbolic link to it in **C:\Users[USER].android** with the same name.

If you wonder how to do this, first install [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html). After folder movement right click on it and select **Pick Link Source** then right click in .android folder and in **Drop As...** sub menu select **Symbolic Link**.

Comment: this works and honestly it should be much higher. additionally, you can create a symbolic link for `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images`, that place eats a lot of space as well. you don't need to use any third-party tools, `mklink /D system-images D:\path\to\system-images` works just fine

Answer (score 1):

I followed https://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/761-move-android-studio-avd-folder-to-a-new-location.

1. Start copying a folder "C:\Users\user\.android\avd" to "D:\Android\.android\avd" (or something else).
2. Close Android Studio and running emulators.
3. Press `Win + Break` and open `Advanced System Settings`. Then press `Environment Variables`. Add a user variable `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`. (I didn't experiment with `ANDROID_AVD_HOME`.) In `Variable value` field write `D:\Android`. If you also moved SDK to another folder, change `ANDROID_HOME` (I forgot to change it and some emulators didn't launch, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57408085/2914140).
4. Wait until the folder will finish copying and start Android Studio.
5. Open `Android Virtual Device Manager` and see a list of emulators. If you don't see emulators and they existed, then probably you entered wrong path into user variable value in step 3. In this case close AS, change the variable and open AS again.
6. Start any emulator. It will try to restore it's state, but it sometimes ***fails***. A black screen can appear instead of Android wallpaper.
7. In this case you can:

   a. Restart your emulator. To do this close running emulator, then in AVD Manager click `Cold Boot Now`.

[image]

b. If this didn't help, open emulator settings, found in file "D:\Android\.android\avd\Pixel_API_27.ini".

[image]

Change a path to a new AVD folder. Restart the emulator.

8. Delete old AVD folder from "C:\Users\user\.android\avd".

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 :
`ANDROID_SDK_HOME`

[this link](https://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/761-move-android-studio-avd-folder-to-a-new-location) helped me.

Then just moved all content of "`avd`" to the new location. Now you may need to change the value of "`path=`" in the `configuration Setting` file of each avds to the new location. You can see the old avds in `avd manager` in Android Studio and they work.

Answer (score 0):

Variable name: ANDROID_SDK_HOME
Variable value: C:\Users>User Name

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

ANDROID_SDK_HOME also worked for me on Windows 8 x64
also find all location (in my case it was d:\.android) and delete it. You won't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In AVD manager, after setting up AVD using a target with `Google APIs`, on run was getting error.

> Detail showed: "AVD Unknown target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:...... "

During install (on Win7 system) I had chosen a SDK directory location, instead of accepting `C:\Users\...`
I'd then added that directory to environment variable *'path'*
Command line: *android list targets* did show a couple of Google apis.

Setting `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` to my install path fixed the avd run error.

Answer (score 0):

**MacOs**
Get a directory adv

```
./emulator -help-datadir
```

the default directory is:

```
/Users/{your_computer_user_name}/.android
```

and then Go to avd Folder edit .ini file with path to your custom emulator directory
example :

> path=/Volumes/Macintos/_emulatorandroid/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd
>       path.rel=avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd
>       target=android-27

and then save. Now your Emulator haschange

[image]

And Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables.html, ANDROID_AVD_HOME is correct.

However, for some unknown reason, it's not working after setting the environment variable at either user or system level. I tried with java code System.getenv('ANDROID_AVD_HOME'), the new environment variable was not being read by java.

A workaround is to modify studio64.exe.vmoptions (or studio.exe.vmoptions) and add -DANDROID_AVD_HOME=D:\ANDROID\avd.