# Moving default AVD configuration folder (.android)

Tags: windows, android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

After installation of Android SDK, the folder `.android` was created on the `E:\` drive. As far as I know, this is the default folder of Android Virtual Devices for configuration files.

How can I move `.android` folder to a different location?

(eg. from `E:\.android` to `E:\Android\.android`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to change where Android Virtual Devices are saved?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841766/possible-to-change-where-android-virtual-devices-are-saved)

Answer (score 237, accepted):

**I've found the answer.**

- Move `.android` folder to `E:\Android`
- Create environment variable called
  **ANDROID_SDK_HOME** and set its value to
  `E:\Android`

Setting the environment variable on Windows XP or Windows 7:

1. Right-click on My Computer and choose "Properties"
2. Click the "Advanced" tab
3. Click the button "Environment Variables".
4. Add New variable

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me.  I was running out of space on C: where it initially put all the AVD files and was causing other problems with the computer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Many other sources suggested changing the `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`, but the detail about copying the `.android` folder was the last missing piece.

Comment: @luiscubal, just using window explorer copy and paste.

Comment: On Windows 10, I had to make sure to add ANDROID_SDK_HOME within the existing PATH variable. It did NOT work when I added it as a new environment variable.

Comment: I had to make sure .android was a subdirectory of the ANDROID_SDK_HOME for it to be found.  This makes sense to me as the .android directory is not the sdk directory (at least in Android Studio 2.2.2)

Comment: thanks, this is the correct answer. is this possible to use the same method for changing the location of `.AndroidStudio2.1` and `.gradle` folders of Android Studio?

Comment: @ir-tech you can override the default `~/.gradle` location by setting the GRADLE_USER_HOME environmental variable

Comment: If your AVDs don't work anymore, you can recreate them.

Comment: I had to update `path` in each avd .ini file, otherwise they were showing up as corrupted.

Comment: Still valid instructions. I can use Android Studio and Visual Studio 2019 without problems, after setting the variable.

Answer (score 27):

By default, the emulator stores configuration files under `$HOME/.android/` and AVD data under `$HOME/.android/avd/`. You can override the defaults by setting the following environment variables.

The emulator searches the avd directory in the order of the values in `$ANDROID_AVD_HOME`, `$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd/`, and `$HOME/.android/avd/`.

This page provides the list of environmental variables supported by android studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 12):

If you go for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3110562/11385066)  be aware of [this note](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables):
Starting with Android Studio 4.2, the ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable is deprecated and has been replaced with ANDROID_PREFS_ROOT.

Answer (score 9):

The path set in `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` must exist. Otherwise the default path will be chosen.
But it is not necessary to include `.android`. The AVD Manager creates a `.android` folder, if not found in `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`.

Comment: I confirmed these instructions are correct as of Android Studio 2.2.2 in 2016.  As long as your .android folder is a subdirectory of the ANDROID_SDK_HOME it works.  It can be a user or system environment variable

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the answer provided by `Dariusz Bacinski`, you have to include the `.android` folder in the `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` path. It was not working for me if I did not include the `.android` folder.

Comment: I've tried both, still not working for me either way. I have a honeycomb tablet and a gingerbread phone to test on, but one of my computers doesn't like Motorola's drivers for whatever reason, so I need an AVD.

Comment: hmm, nevermind. Changing the debug keystore from default seems to have solved the problem for some reason.

Comment: This is not correct - it will look for a .android SUB-folder under the ANDROID_SDK_HOME, so following these instructions does not work.  See the answer below

Comment: I already copied `avd` inside `%ANDROID_SDK_HOME %\.android`, so no more folders were needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to move just the AVD folder and not everything else, use those environmental variables.

> ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME: Sets the path to the user-specific emulator configuration directory. The default location is
> $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/.

> ANDROID_AVD_HOME: Sets the path to the directory that contains all AVD-specific files, which mostly consist of very large disk images. The default location is $ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME/avd/. You might want to specify a new location if the default location is low on disk space.

Answer (score 2):

0. (Optional) Download [Rapid Environment Editor](https://www.rapidee.com/en/download)
1. Add a new system variable

> ANDROID_PREFS_ROOT = D:\IDE\Externals\ANDROID_PREFS_ROOT (The folder you want to move to.)

2. Save and you're done.

Comment: that is the correct solution for the new version 2023, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Chosen answer is kinda outdated.

As of Giraffe | 2022.3.1 (Stable): when changing the default android avd folder, you need to add a new environment variable for **ANDROID_USER_HOME**. The value should lead to the location of the new folder, in your case:

```
ANDROID_USER_HOME = E:\Android\.android
```

If you have android studio with a lower version (4.3 or earlier), you have to use **ANDROID_SDK_HOME** instead of **ANDROID_USER_HOME**.

```
ANDROID_SDK_HOME = E:\Android
```

> To override the user preferences location for those
> older tools, set ANDROID_SDK_HOME to the parent directory you would
> like the .android directory to be created under.

If you have AVDs and you're not able to run them after changing the location of the `.android` folder.

[image: Error thrown when running an emulator]

Then you might want to look at the `*.ini` configuration file of each of your AVDs. It is located inside the avd folder `E:\Android\.android\avd`
[image: Inside the AVD folder]

If each emulator's `path` does not lead to the new specified location, correct it.
[image: Correct way of AVD paths]

Answer (score 1):

If you would like your avd sdcard and files on a different drive, go to `$HOME/.android/avd` and move the folder `<AVD_NAME>.avd` to someplace else

Edit `$HOME/.android/avd/<AVD_NAME>.ini` and change

```
path=<NEW_AVD_LOCATION>/<AVD_NAME>.avd
```

`$HOME` depends on your system. On windows it can be your user directory