# How to change .android path

Tags: android, sdk, virtual

I installed android sdk. But i have a problem AVD.

When i created new avd and i started the my android program , The path is fault.

My path is C:\Users\Barış.android. The fault is Turkish character.

How to change new avm path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving default AVD configuration folder (.android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109473/moving-default-avd-configuration-folder-android)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109473/moving-default-avd-configuration-folder-android). I think the answer provided there could be the solution to yours too.