# Problem with emulator creation

Tags: android, emulation

I have android 3.2 and android 2.3.3 installed in eclipse.Whenever i am creating AVD it is showing error in console that **"Error: Target location is not inside the SDK."** and 
 **"Failed to set image path properties in the AVD folder."** Anyone having idea how to solve it ?

Answer (score 4):

I got this when my avd folder path had spaces in it and was on a network share.  If there is anything "unusual" about your avd  folder (spaces, special characters, network share, long path) I would suggest moving it to something simple like c:\avd

There is a question that deals with moving the folder here: [Moving default AVD configuration folder (.android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109473/moving-default-avd-configuration-folder-android)

Once I had reconfigured the folder I had to reboot my PC before it would work.

Answer (score 4):

```
SET ANDROID_SDK_HOME variable not working for me.
```

1. Open eclipse
2. Click on window menu and then select preference.
3. Select android from left hand side.
4. Now SET SDK location `e.g. E:\android\sdk instead of ../sdk` means set `Absolute path` instead of `Relative path`.

Its worked for me.

I hope this help someone and save time.

Answer (score 1):

Try these:
1-Open Eclipse launcher's properties (not shortcut's)
2-Select "compatibility" tab
3-Check "Run this program as an administrator"
4-OK

Answer (score 0):

If you're SDK path is relative, change it to an absolute path.

This was happening to me when launching the manager from Eclipse where I had the SDK path configured as a relative path and not an absolute path.  Changing the path to an absolute one fixed the issue.