# I want to change .android folder

Tags: android

first time as a questioner! I've been reading for a while and i cant find the solution. We're using Android Studio at college, and we have frozen computers (restarts data every day, except 1 folder). The .android folder is at /home/user by default, and that gets overwrited every day so i cant save my avd config. Is there any chance to change the whole folder location? (We're using ubuntu 12.04) Thx m8s!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109473/moving-default-avd-configuration-folder-android <- it is for windows, but should help get you started in a direction.

Comment: Thx, ill try with taht if not ill ask again! Thx anyway :)