# Is it possible to allocate these folders in another place?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am installing `Android Studio` and I have by default the path `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk` to set my `SDK`. If I choose this option, some folders appeared on the path `C:\Users\Administrator`.

These folders are:

- .android
- .AndroidStudio1.3
- .oracle_jre_usage
- .gradle

To be a little more cleaner I tried to wrap all these folders into another folder but each time I run `Android Studio` it gives to me the option to configure again the settings. If I configure them again, the folders re-appeared on the path `C:\Users\Administrator`.

What can I do to wrap these folders into another one or to set another location for them and that the settings will be saved?

---

**EDIT:** I prove the solutions on the blog of the answer provided by `Rahul Tiwari` but I only could get that the folder `.android` will be in the new folder. The rest folders are at the same location after the changes.

---

**EDIT 2:** According to the blog provided by `Rahul Tiwari` to move the folder `.gradle` I change the default settings of `Android Studio`:

```
File > Other Settings... > Default Settings... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle
```

Here I have as **Service directory path:** `C:/Users/Administrator/AndroidStudio/.gradle`

But the folder `.gradle` still appears on the path `C:/Users/Administrator`.

---

**EDIT 3:** Trying to remove the folder `.AndroidStudio1.3` I changed these lines:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to user installed plugins folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# idea.plugins.path=${idea.config.path}/plugins

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE logs folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# idea.log.path=${idea.system.path}/log
```

to these:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to user installed plugins folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.plugins.path=${C:/Users/Administrator/AndroidStudio/.AndroidStudio1.3/config}/plugins

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE logs folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.log.path=${C:/Users/Administrator/AndroidStudio/.AndroidStudio1.3/system}/log
```

but I also couldn't move the folder.

---

**EDIT 4:** This is the [blog](http://www.littlecpu.com/android-studio-c-drive) that I mention before (Thank you very much `Rahul Tiwari`). I post it here because his answer was deleted.

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving default AVD configuration folder (.android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109473/moving-default-avd-configuration-folder-android)

Comment: @RahulTiwari It still puts these folders on `C:\Users\Administrator`.

Comment: Tell us what exactly you tried.

Comment: @RahulTiwari I created a new folder on `C:\Users\Administrator\Android Studio` and set the `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` with that path. After, I reboot the computer and move the folders that I put above into the new folder named `Android Studio`. When I go to the `Android Studio` desktop icon to execute it, `Android Studio` again gives to me the option to configure my settings or to import them from another version of `Android Studio`.

Comment: Check carefully for any typo and try removing space from folder name 'Android Studio'. I have tried this solution and it is working fine.

Comment: @RahulTiwari What do you mean with "for any typo"?

Comment: from 'typo' in mean any spelling mistakes

Comment: @RahulTiwari Ok, now the folder `.android` it's located on the new folder but `.AndroidStudio1.3`, `oracle_jre_usage` and `.gradle` folders are still on the path `C:\Users\Administrator`.

Comment: refer first section from [blog post](http://www.littlecpu.com/android-studio-c-drive) for `.gradle` folder. I have no idea about oracle related folder though

Comment: @RahulTiwari Yes, I tried with the sections of `.gradle` and `.AndroidStudio1.3` but still the same behaviour.

Comment: **Look that I completed my answer with the solution for `.gradle` folder. Now I just need a solution to move `.oracle_jre_usage` folder.**

Comment: you should include link of the blog somewhere in your question and answer as well, as it is being referred everywhere and my answer got deleted.

Comment: @RahulTiwari Do you have the link of the blog? I didn't notice that your answer was deleted and I didn't save it.

Comment: @Heyyou I'm not sure what do you mean with your question. I found the solution to move three of the folders, but I still need a solution to move `.oracle_jre_usage` folder. Do you know a solution for that?

Comment: @Heyyou Ok thank you for your time!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution to move three of the folders that I put above. I think it could be interesting to put here the problems that I faced and the changes that I made to solve them.

**I'm going to investigate about the last folder, `.oracle_jre_usage`, and I will complete this answer if I got a solution for it. Look that I complete the solution for `.gradle` folder.**

---

**To move `.android` folder**

Really, following the steps of the blog that `Rahul Tiwari` provided, this folder could been moved. Nevertheless I'm going to put here all the process:

- You have to move your `.android` folder, after closing `Android Studio` (if you have it running), to the folder in which you want that it will be stored, in my case, `C:\Users\Administrator\AndroidStudio`.
- **BEWARE WITH THE SPACES IN THE NAME OF THE NEW FOLDER, IT COULD GIVE TO YOU PROBLEMS (AS ME).** I mean, `Android Studio`, `New Folder` or similars.
- If you are on `Windows`, you can do right-click on `My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables` and create a new environment variable named `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` and as value you have to put the new path in which `.android` folder will be stored. It's the same path in which you have moved the `.android` folder in the step above.
- Click "OK" button to accept your changes.
- Re-launch `Android Studio` and look that the `.android` folder doesn't appear in the default path.

---

**To move `.AndroidStudio1.3` folder**

With that folder I had some problems because I didn't noticed some details that were very important. Here the steps that I followed:

- First of all, you have to close `Android Studio` before doing any change.
- After, you have to move the folder `.AndroidStudio1.3` to the path in which you want that it will be stored.
- Next, you have to go to the folder in which `Android Studio` were installed and open "idea.properties" file and changed the lines where **idea.config.path** and **idea.system.path** appeared for the new path in which these folders are going to be located.

They have to be something similar to this:

```
idea.config.path=C:/Users/Administrator/AndroidStudio/.AndroidStudio1.3/config

idea.system.path=C:/Users/Administrator/AndroidStudio/.AndroidStudio1.3/system
```

> Here I had three problems so please **be careful**:

> - Notice that the paths are with `/` and not with `\` as `Windows` put by default.

> - **DON'T CHANGE** the values of **idea.plugins.path** and **idea.log.path** (My EDIT 3). Be sure that you are changing **idea.config.path** and **idea.system.path** values.

> - Uncomment the lines in which **idea.config.path** and **idea.system.path** appears. I mean, remove the `#` that they have at the begining of each line.

- The last step, re-launch `Android Studio`.

---

Searching and doing some proves I also get the solution to move `.gradle` folder. The steps are the same as `.android` folder but I put here all the steps (with the values that changed) to avoid any confusion. Here it is:

**To move `.gradle` folder**

- You have to move your `.gradle` folder, after closing `Android Studio` (if you have it running), to the folder in which you want that it will be stored, in my case, `C:\Users\Administrator\AndroidStudio\.gradle`.
- **BEWARE WITH THE SPACES IN THE NAME OF THE NEW FOLDER, IT COULD GIVE TO YOU PROBLEMS (AS ME).** I mean, `Android Studio`, `New Folder` or similars.
- If you are on `Windows`, you can do right-click on `My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables` and create a new environment variable named `GRADLE_USER_HOME` and as value you have to put the new path in which `.gradle` folder will be stored. It's the same path in which you have moved the `.gradle` folder in the step above.
- Click "OK" button to accept your changes.
- Re-launch `Android Studio` and look that the `.gradle` folder doesn't appear in the default path.

---

Comment: Today I made an observation, although I had successfully moved `.gradle` folder to other location it got created again at its default location, but it is only having some empty folders. I think gradle is referring the configured folder however there is some bug somewhere which is creating this folder again at default location.

Comment: @RahulTiwari I finally found a solution to totally move the folder `.gradle`. I edited my question. Maybe it could help you. Do you know something about how to move `.oracle_jre_usage` folder?

Comment: nice efforts. seems like spaces were problems all the time ;) .Unfortunately, I did it only for 3 folders which worked for you. I don't have a JRE folder like you have.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the .oracle_jre_usage?

Comment: @hitch.united Not yet. It seems that it was a bug for some versions of Java: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8134300

Comment: @Error404, I found that the method which you provided is not working in Android Studio version 2.2.2. The folder .AndroidStudio2.2 is still created at default location although I have changed the `idea.properties`

Comment: @Kane I am sorry for that long time without giving a response but I did not seen it before. Yes, you are right. I have checked it now for Android 2.2 and it is creating two folders, 1 on the path that I have declared and another on the home path. The last one is created with an empty system folder, though. I will investigare a bit further about this these days.

Comment: @Error404, thank you for your reply. I would waiting for your reply and also trying to look for another solutions if I can get one. Thanks.

Comment: no idea why it's still creating .gradle folder in C drive although I've moved it to D drive, doesn't work for me

Comment: be aware of `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` env variable, this is deprecated in Android Studio 4.2 and must be changed to 'ANDROID_PREFS_ROOT', see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables) for clarification.

Answer (score 17):

How to move data from %UserProfile%

The folders will still remain under %UserProfile%, but not the data.

---

### Move .android

1. Android Studio is closed
2. Add Environment Variable

   Create "System variable":

   Variable name: ANDROID_SDK_HOME

   Variable value: D:\Android

---

### Move .AndroidStudio

This is a example with Android Studio version 3.1

1. Start Android Studio
2. Help -> Edit Custom Properties...
3. Click Yes to create file
4. Edit file with:

   idea.config.path=D:/Android/.AndroidStudio3.1/config

   idea.system.path=D:/Android/.AndroidStudio3.1/system
5. The file "idea.properties" is located under:

   %UserProfile%/.AndroidStudio3.1/config
6. Close Android Studio
7. Delete all under %UserProfile%/.AndroidStudio3.1 except the file "/config/idea.properties"
8. Optional: Delete older version folders of .AndroidStudio

Don't edit "Android Studio/bin/idea.properties". When updating Android Studio this file is cleared.

---

## Move .gradle

1. Start Android Studio
2. File -> Settings... -> Gradle
3. Change "Service directory path" to:

   D:/Android/.gradle

---

## Update Android Studio

1. Start Android Studio
2. "Import Studio settings from" is showed
3. Select: D:/Android/.AndroidStudio3.0/config

Comment: I got this error when Updating AS "Cannot find file 'D:\Android\.AndroidStudio3.0\config\settings.jar'"

Comment: @BeeingJk, Open Android Studio and do the steps 1,2,3 for "Move .AndroidStudio" and you can see were Android Studio create the file in the title bar. Look were the arrow is pointing and you can see the file location.
http://cdn.ilovefreesoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/colored-title-bar-window.png

Comment: Android Studio version 3.0 have another location for "idea.properties":
%UserProfile%/.AndroidStudio3.0/

Comment: Thanks. I have done steps 'Move .AndroidStudio', but the file location is still in C:\Users\<user>\.AndroidStudio3.0 rather than D drive

Comment: C:\Users\kahbee\.AndroidStudio3.0\system is recreated when I open AS3.0, but inside \system is empty

Comment: the idea,.properties is created at the same level of system folder https://ibb.co/gQ84jd

Comment: The file location will always be:
C:\Users\<user>\.AndroidStudio3.0 and \system is always recreated and empty. You have done it right. Yay :)
All data should now be in D:\Android\.AndroidStudio3.0\config

Comment: Owh..I see!! I thought an error in my build.gradle(ConfigSlurper not found) is because of that(pointing wrong path), haha..thanks a lot for pointing it out. Narrowed down the range for the error fixing.

Comment: But the error "Cannot find file 'D:\Android\.AndroidStudio3.0\config\settings.jar'" still exist, I never completed last step, doesn't it a potential issue?

Comment: Move .AndroidStudio is working fine for you? The problem is when you now start AS? Is it when you import studio settings, do this. Now you should import your old .AndroidStudio2.3 settings. It's located under %UserProfile%/.AndroidStudio2.3/config or D:/Android/.AndroidStudio2.3/config

Comment: Yea '.AndroidStudio3.0' is already in my D drive and I am able to launch AS3 without issue, just that if now I do "Import Studio settings" and select: D:/Android/.AndroidStudio3.0/config, it will show the error. I've lost my AS2.3 config

Comment: If you did a upgrade from AS2.3 to AS3.0 you should not import AS3.0 config, it should be AS2.3 config.

Comment: got it, should be OK without importing old config

Comment: The step "Update Android Studio" is to import old config.
Only when you want to import old config do this step, if's not important - skip this and AS create one for you :)

Comment: `Move .AndroidStudio` if do this step, then it's not possible to update plugins in Android Studio, other steps works ok

Answer (score 2):

I think most of the others answers address the issue, But I found more simple way for windows by adding few environment variables . (Might work for mac as well, I didn't test though)

ANDROID_SDK_ROOT - path to the SDK installation directory

default path - C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Add enviroment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT - set value to desired location
Eg: =E:\Android\local\Android\Sdk

For `.android` folder
default path - C:\Users\XXXX\.android
Add enviroment variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME- set value to desired location
Eg: = E:\Android

For `.gradle` folder
default path - C:\Users\XXXX\.gradle
Add enviroment variable GRADLE_USER_HOME - set value to desired location
Eg: = E:\Android\.gradle

For `.androidstudioXXX`

Android Studio-> Help-> Edit Custom Properties
Add below lines

idea.config.path=E:/Android/.AndroidStudio4.0/config
idea.system.path=E:/Android/.AndroidStudio4.0/system

Add environment variable STUDIO_PROPERTIES - set value to desired location
Eg: = E:\Android\idea.properties

Finally don't forget to copy files from the original location to the new location.

Source : https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables
Please see the end of the page to know how to add the environment variable on Windows, Mac or Linux

Answer (score 1):

At least for Android 3.0 the steps in the accepted solution are not enough to be able to run the emulators after moving the **.android** folder (let's say you moved the folder from `c:\Users\<username>\.android` to `I:\Programs\AppData\.android`). 
In addition you need to

1. Copy (or leave) files adbkey and adbkey.pub  in old location (i.e. `c:\Users\<username>\.android\adbkey`, `c:\Users\<username>\.android\adbkey.pub`)
2. Replace the old location path string `C:\Users\<username>\` in all .INI files found in the new avd location (i.e. in `I:\Programs\AppData\.android\avd`) with the new location path string `I:\Programme\AppData\`
3. Delete all `*.qcow2` files from the new avd location (`i:\Programme\AppData\.android\avd`) which contain the old location path string `c:\Users\<username>\`. Check [Qcow2-files refer to incorrect/nonexistent base-images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645178/panic-broken-avd-system-path-check-your-android-sdk-root-value) for an alternative to delete the *.qcow2 files. If you delete the files all data in the emulator is lost, in this case you will get a clean version of Android, like after a hard reset.

Answer (score 0):

To change default .gradle folder using Android Studio 2.2

Open folder of .AndroidStudiox.x (x.x is the version you use) -> config -> options -> gradle.settings.xml file

just right click to open it with wordpad, you should only see 1 option name = serviceDirectoryPath, change the value of that to desired path

remember use / not backward slash \ for folder even in Windows OS

Answer (score 0):

I use junction.exe from Sysinternals to make my Java/Android Studio fully "portable" in Windows:

1. I have "AndroidStudio" installed in a folder "work".
2. I have "Java\jdk1.8.0_77_x64" in the same "work".
3. In the same folder "work" I copied the original ".android", ".AndroidStudio2.2" and ".gradle" folders (from C:\Users\<*YourProfile*>).
4. Then in the same parent folder "work" I have copied "junction.exe".
5. Finally in the same "work" I have a batch __init__.bat with content listed below.
6. Closed Android Studio and deleted original ".android", ".AndroidStudio2.2" and ".gradle" folders (from C:\Users\<*YourProfile*>).
7. Run __init__.bat (as Administrator to set also the **JAVA_PATH** via setx) to create the new junctions then restart Android Studio. This solution works also after I reimage Windows, just have to remeber to run first the mentioned bat...

PS: When I update java or upgrade Android I have to remeber to tweak the bat with the new revision numbers

Content of __init__.bat:

```
@echo off
@SET mySrcPath=%cd%
@rem echo "%myPath%"
@rem JAVA_HOME = D:\work\Android\Java\jdk1.8.0_77_x64\
@SET myJavaTarget=Java\jdk1.8.0_77_x64\
@SET myJavaPath=%mySrcPath%\%myJavaTarget%
@if not exist "%myJavaPath%" (
    @echo CANNOT FIND myJavaPath = "%myJavaPath%"
    @goto _exit_
 )
@rem echo myJavaPath = "%myJavaPath%"
@setx JAVA_HOME %myJavaPath%

@SET myTargetPath=%USERPROFILE%
@SET myCopy1=.android
@SET myCopy2=.AndroidStudio2.2
@SET myCopy3=.gradle
@SET mySource1="%mySrcPath%\%myCopy1%"
@SET mySource2="%mySrcPath%\%myCopy2%"
@SET mySource3="%mySrcPath%\%myCopy3%"
@SET myTarget1="%myTargetPath%\%myCopy1%"
@SET myTarget2="%myTargetPath%\%myCopy2%"
@SET myTarget3="%myTargetPath%\%myCopy3%"
@rem echo.

@if not exist %mySource1% (
    @echo CANNOT FIND mySource1 = %mySource1%
    @goto _exit_
)

@if not exist %mySource2% (
    @echo CANNOT FIND mySource2 = %mySource2%
    @goto _exit_
)

@if not exist %mySource3% (
    @echo CANNOT FIND mySource3 = %mySource3%
    @goto _exit_
)

@if not exist %myTarget1% (
    @echo creating myTarget1 = %myTarget1% from  mySource1 = %mySource1%
    @junction.exe %myTarget1% %mySource1%
) else (
    @echo myTarget1 = %myTarget1% ALREADY EXISTS !!!!!!
)

@if not exist %myTarget2% (
    @echo creating myTarget2 = %myTarget2% from  mySource2 = %mySource2%
    @junction.exe %myTarget2% %mySource2%
) else (
    @echo myTarget2 = %myTarget2% ALREADY EXISTS !!!!!!
)

@if not exist %myTarget3% (
    @echo creating myTarget3 = %myTarget3% from  mySource3 = %mySource3%
    @junction.exe %myTarget3% %mySource3%
) else (
    @echo myTarget3 = %myTarget3% ALREADY EXISTS !!!!!!
)


:_exit_

@echo exiting...
@pause
```