# Config path Android studio is invalid

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, windows-10

I'm not sure if anyone else has seen this before but I got a windows update a few days ago and ever since my android studio fails to open. The exact error message I'm getting is:

```
Config path C:/windows/system32/config/systemprofile/.AndroidSudio.3/config is
 invalid. If you have modified the 'idea.config.path' property please make 
sure it is correct, otherwise please re-install the IDE.
```

When I run it in Admin mode it goes through the installation again.
 I don't want to have to do this every time I open it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to allocate these folders in another place?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759785/is-it-possible-to-allocate-these-folders-in-another-place)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run Android Studio as Administrator and it will create the idea.properties files

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: But, this allows be to run only as admin ?

Comment: @DineshVG You only have to run Android Studio as admin for the first time.

Comment: Just in case anyone arrives here, and wonders how to do that, `cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/` and `sudo ./studio` seemed to do it for me

Answer (score 0):

Does that config path exist?

Android Studio is based on IntelliJ. See [IntelliJ Idea Properties](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/file-idea-properties.html) for where to modify your idea.properties file - and modify **idea.config.path** as described at the bottom of [IntelliJ Idea - Project and IDE Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/project-and-ide-settings.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I installed AndroidStudio 1.5 on my windows 10 laptop after I uninstalled an older version of Android Studio. To fix it, I followed the instructions at the Android developer website: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration.

First, do not modify the idea.properties file located in the bin folder where Android Studio is installed. Older stack overflow posts will tell you to modify that idea.properites file, but you aren't supposed to do so for AndroidStudio 1.5. By following the instructions, I created an idea.properties file at **%USERPROFILE%\.{FOLDER_NAME}\idea.properties**.  If you have installed AndroidStudio 1.5, then .{FOLDER_NAME} should be .{AndroidStudio1.5}.  The content of my idea.properties file is the following:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# IDEA can copy library .jar files to prevent their locking.
# By default this behavior is enabled on Windows and disabled on other platforms.
# Uncomment this property to override.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# idea.jars.nocopy=false

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# The VM option value to be used to start a JVM in debug mode.
# Some JREs define it in a different way (-XXdebug in Oracle VM)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.xdebug.key=-Xdebug

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Change to 'enabled' if you want to receive instant visual notifications
# about fatal errors that happen to an IDE or plugins installed.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.fatal.error.notification=disabled

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE config folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.config.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudio1.5/config

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE system folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.system.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudio1.5/system

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to user installed plugins folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.plugins.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudio1.5/config/plugins

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE logs folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.log.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudio1.5/system/log
```

Answer (score 0):

to fix this you need to open it as admin, you can do that by the terminal or just open the Finder folder, find the application, right-click and open as admin in windows or just open in mac