# Moving .AndroidStudio1.5 folder off the C: Drive

Tags: android-studio

I've been trying without much success to prevent Android Studio 1.5 from writing to my C: drive ever (small boot SSD). Also, I'm running on Windows 7. I have gotten it to move the .android folder to my HDD pretty easily, but can't quite seem to get it to stop creating the .AndroidStudio1.5 file on my C: drive. I have tried :

- creating an idea.properties inside the AndroidStudio1.5 file that sets the idea.system.path and idea.config.path ... but that doesn't quite address the fact that I don't want to add anything to my C: drive, and I have no evidence that the C: drive file won't be used.
- I've looked in the registry, and there isn't anything I can see to edit this default. I symbolically link my Desktop to my HDD, so [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759785/is-it-possible-to-allocate-these-folders-in-another-place) would suggest I should be fine, and that the default .AndroidStudio1.5 folder should automatically be created on my HDD, but that's not the case.
- I've copied the .AndroidStudio1.5 folder over to my HDD and when asked if I want to use a previous config file, I give it my config file on my HDD. It still recreates the .AndroidStudio1.5 file on my C: drive after I restart AS.
- I've looked for other answers, and haven't found any specifically relating to changing the default location of the .AndroidStudio1.5 folder to an entirely different drive.

Thanks for any help in advance.

EDIT: I have symbolically linked the .AndroidStudio1.5 folder to the HDD and that works, but as I mentioned in my comment, I would like to know how to do this inside the program itself so that it stops looking for the folder in the C drive, although since it will have the same effect of not storing anything in my C drive, this is more out of curiosity than anything.

Comment: Depending on where the file is, if it is on the AndroidStudio foider, you can create a symlink to your HDD

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why I hadn't thought of that... having symbolically linked my personal folders for the same purpose... I'll reply back with how that goes. I would still like to know how I would get the program to do this instead of my OS though. Something that hacks less and forces the program to do what I want it to do more would be awesome.

Comment: For those forlders, you can just move them using the properties window. To the program, i have no idea

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!
In idea.properties file the path must be (i.e.):
"e:\\path\\.AndroidStudio1.5\\config"
Use two backslashes instead one.

Comment: How does this answer the question or even speak to the question?

Comment: It speaks to the question if you know which file path he's referencing. It's the idea.config.path and the idea.system.path settings that must be included in the idea.properties file. In Android 1.3 they were in the properties file to begin with from my understanding, and now they definitely are not. If this works, I will edit the answer and accept it as the correct answer.