# Change .androidstudio2.1 folder path

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I searched alot to change the path of **.androidstudio2.1**  I searched for it, and the internet suggested me to change the settings in **idea.properties**
and that is my **idea.properties** file  :

```
idea.config.path=D:/Android/.AndroidStudio2.1/config
idea.config.pathh=D:/Android/.AndroidStudio2.1/system
```

and i moved **.AndroidStudio2.1** to **D:/Android** I started Android Studio and it told me I should import settings to complete the installation.
and it recreated **.AndroidStudio2.1** again in **C**

i found this link but i didnot understand what should i do :)
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

Comment: what you want exactly do you want to change studio path or samething else [see here],(http://www.littlecpu.com/android-studio-c-drive);

Comment: @AmitBasliyal i want to change the path of that folder .AndroidStudio2.1
and this is itis real path C:\Users\Dell

Comment: @AmitBasliyal Hello about that link http://www.littlecpu.com/android-studio-c-drive
i make all the setps and all the steps is ok but the last step (Cache Folder)
is not working on version 2.1

Comment: http://www.laurivan.com/android-studio-change-the-location-of-androidstudiobeta/ ope link and their is link

Comment: @AmitBasliyal sorry what is ${user.home} how can i put it in this two
idea.config.path=D:/Android/.AndroidStudio2.1/config   

idea.config.pathh=D:/Android/.AndroidStudio2.1/system

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to allocate these folders in another place?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759785/is-it-possible-to-allocate-these-folders-in-another-place)

Answer (score 10):

Cache Folder :

[image]

Our last step is to move presumably cache folder for AS. This involves editing a text file of AS to tell AS to refer to custom location for cache folder.

1. Close AS if any.
2. Move .AndroidStudio to destination drive (e.g. D:\Android)
3. Go to the folder where AS is installed (e.g. C:\Program Files\Android Studio).
4. Go to bin directory and edit idea.propertis file using your favourite text editor.
5. Uncomment and edit the following two lines. Point them to new location:

idea.config.path
idea.system.path

Re-launch AS again. Make sure .android, .AndroidStudio and .gradle folders are not re-created at C drive. Happy coding.

[See here](http://www.littlecpu.com/android-studio-c-drive)

Comment: I have did those steps, and for the most part, it seems to work and Android Studio loads the ".AndroidStudio" folder from the location I set in "idea.properties" correctly. Except that it also recreates an empty ".AndroidStudio/system" folder and subfolder at each launch.Is there a solution to this problem? Thank you.

Comment: .AndroidStudio is still recreated, I'm using AS3.0

Answer (score 1):

If you want the **.AndroidStudio2.1** folder created inside the **Android Studio** IDE location:

> Use ${idea.home.path} macro to specify location relative to IDE installation home

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE config folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.config.path=${idea.home.path}/.AndroidStudio2.1/config

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this option if you want to customize path to IDE system folder. Make sure you're using forward slashes.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.system.path=${idea.home.path}/.AndroidStudio2.1/system
```

[image]