# How to move .AndroidStudio3.1 Folder?

Tags: windows, android-studio

I have looked at [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759785/is-it-possible-to-allocate-these-folders-in-another-place?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). but that didn't seem to work for me because I am unsure about what `Francisco Romero` (chosen answer) said when he said **idea.config.path** and **idea.system.path**. I was unsure about what exactly I was supposed to edit and none of the other answers on the question helped.

I just want to be able to move this folder correctly to my E: drive then be able to use Android Studio from there.

My path is `C:\Users\NAME\.AndroidStudio3.1` and I'm on a Windows Laptop if that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to allocate these folders in another place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759785/is-it-possible-to-allocate-these-folders-in-another-place)

Answer (score 5):

I may be late, but follow these steps to move the **.AndroidStudioX.Y** to your desired location:

1. Close Android Studio if running.
2. Move .AndroidStudioX.Y folder to new location.
3. Go to the folder where Android Studio is installed (e.g. C:\Program
   Files\Android Studio).
4. Go to bin folder and edit **idea.properties** file using a text editor.
5. Uncomment these lines and edit them like in the example image:

**idea.config.path**

**idea.system.path**

[image: Example image]

[Source here](http://www.littlecpu.com/android-studio-c-drive).