# After moving .gradle,.android & .androidStudio3.1 folders to E drive facing few issues

Tags: android, android-studio

As per the solution provided in this link 
[Is it possible to allocate these folders in another place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759785/is-it-possible-to-allocate-these-folders-in-another-place)

I have followed the each step of accepted solution, i have moved .gradle,.android & .androidStudio3.1 in to E drive from C

Build is Successful,but when i tried to open with an emulator i'm facing the following error

> Emulator: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "file:/C:/Users/saiteja/.AndroidStudio3.1/config/options/updates.xml"

when i debugged i was able to find the updates.xml file under this path `E:\androidfiles.AndroidStudio3.1\config\options` (migrated path)

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: E:\androidfiles.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_24.avd/userdata.img

How to fix these error or am i missing to change of the files?

Answer (score 0):

Enter in `Studio` `AVD Manager` and recreate you emulator again, to restore all previous created dependencies for the `Virtualization`.

Comment: can you please explain in detail, I'm completely new to android.

Comment: I have created a new emulator still i'm facing the same issue