# Android Studio taking up C: space

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio on my D:\ drive, however when i start a project it automatically creates folders in my C:\ drive.

Comment: Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759785/is-it-possible-to-allocate-these-folders-in-another-place