# How to change AVD location in eclipse

Tags: android

Hi How can I change AVD manager location from c:\users\xxx.android to D:\ from eclipse in windows 8

as I am getting out of memory in c drive, I want to move in D drive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109473/moving-default-avd-configuration-folder-android

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a better way to replace all **SDK** to a new location. **You can't change just folder of AVD.** But replacing **SDK** to a new location may produce problems. So, maybe it's a better idea to extend memory of your main system disk, via settings in Windows.