# Emulator process killed while launching

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I am using `Android Studio` 2.2.3

I created a very simple project with the `basic activity`.

When I run the project then there was this error in the `Run` tab : `Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5X_API_25_x86 was killed.`

My computer is windows7 64-bit , RAM 4Gb , virtualization is enabled. There is the antivirus Avast running.

So what should I do to prevent this process killing ?

Answer (score 19):

This problem has multiple reasons, to properly solve this issue go to `Help -> show log in ****`
then open the log file and search the word "Emulator" in that file.
for example, I found this error in the log file
`2020-12-27 22:42:58,708 [114439053]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Not enough disk space`

and the problem solved by making some space.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  For me the problem was caused by me setting the ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable - for some reason this meant Android Studio could no longer find the AVD folder, so I also had to set ANDROID_AVD_HOME=C:\users\...\.android\avd

Comment: Thank you. This is the best answer

Answer (score 14):

[ERROR Android emulator gets killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841461/error-android-emulator-gets-killed/64735945#64735945)

This worked for me:

Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools (tab) -> Deselect 'Android Emulator' -> OK

Now, when you try to run your app, or launch device from AVD Manager, it will give the 'Install Emulator' error -> Click Ok. This will automatically download the correct version.

Comment: it's not work. 
My processor laptop is Xeon, ram 32GB, latest Intel Haxm installed still not work. It's weird when I installed new sdk version for new emulator, "Was Killed" message as always

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helped me =)

Answer (score 8):

If everything else fails, try to run the emulator manually through the command line to see what made it crash.
In my case it was due to the lack of free space on C:. The solution was to free up some space and it went back to life.

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator.exe -avd Pixel_3a_API_30_x86
        emulator: ERROR: Not enough space to create userdata partition. Available: 3853.097656 MB at C:\Users\<user>\.android\avd\Pixel_3a_API_30_x86.avd, need 7372.800000 MB.
        
        
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>
```

Comment: This is the best answer. There seems to be 10+ different causes for this error (why don't they provide the process stderr output in the error message??), so it's really helpful to get some actual details on what is causing the error when debugging it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but then I realized that my Windows user directory name i.e. `C:\Users\myUserName`, wasn't written in English characters, to be exact it had Greek characters, so I changed the directory's name and then the emulator launched.

The emulator is searching inside this directory, because in there the `.android` directory is stored, that contains the emulator's data `'C:\Users\myUserName\.android\avd'`.

So keep that in mind, probably it has to do with a directory name or something.

**Edit:**

You can move the `.android` folder to another drive like (E:). If you do that, you have to add some environment variables to your system. For more info check the link below:

[Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109473/moving-default-avd-configuration-folder-android)

Comment: Same issue, move it out of my user folder with env variables, and issue resolved.

Answer (score 2):

It is an Android Studio Bug in this version(4.1)!

Easy Solution:
go to File-> Settings -> emulator
then Uncheck "Launch in a tool window".

That Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

1. Open folder (**C:\Users\<username>\.android**).
2. Create a file (**advancedFeatures.ini**).
3. Add these lines in the file (**advancedFeatures.ini**).

```
Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
```

4. Now start the **AVD Manager**.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might related to the the GPU drivers,
The problem is that emulators with Google Play feature,
 You can't change from hardware to software, 
Try this using PowerShell or CMD window: (Change user and emulator names accordingly)

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator> .\emulator.exe -avd Pixel_4_API_30 -gpu swiftshader_indirect
```

It will start the emulator using the software,
The disadvantage of this solution is that you need to keep the CMD or PS window open,
No big deal for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem in MacBook pro M1(macOS Big Sur) and i spent alot of time in fixing this.
The solution is simple, I downloaded the android emulator-m1-preview and Android Studio Preview(Arctic Fox)  which is specifically for m1.

https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview
developer.android.com

Comment: Please highlight MacBook Pro M1 so that users can understand that you are giving answer specific for this machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue! if you are not running out of space! check the logs by going to **Help** -> **Show Log in Explorer**!  I got that "**the Avd's CPU Architecture was not supported** " so I went to device manager for the virtual device go to edit and  I changed the image architecture I set a X86 image and it worked!