# Android studio and gradle to download on hard drive block - acer revo build m1-601

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to install Android Studio on an Acer Revo Build M1-601. This is a computer that has a 32GB Hard drive and an external block drive that is 1 Terra. Windows is installed on the 32GB drive and I want to use the computer to learn how to build apps in Android Studio. I managed to change the location of the SDK to D: drive, however, every time that I try to start a new project, the gradle packages are downloading on C:, not on D. Is there something that I am missing? I am a beginner, tried to follow many youtube videos explaining how to install it, even bought a book, still not managing to understand. Can someone help? can someone give simple instructions if they know how to change the download location  to the external drive?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the path from

> **File**
>   **Settings** > Build Execution, Deployment > **Gradle** > Service directory path choose directory what you want.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I've now changed this, however, when I am trying to download / set-up the emulator, everything is being downloaded in Users/$User/appData/Temp. Any way to make it download on the external file? Now I have 0 space on my C:

Comment: This answer might be helpful to change Windows .temp location. :)
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/change-location-of-temp-files-folder-to-another/19f13330-dde1-404c-aa27-a76c0b450818

Comment: Thanks. Will try it and let you know if this solved the problem.

Comment: So, that worked, however the packages still download in C:/Users/ $User/.android

Comment: Do you mean AVD? If so then you can change ".android" folder location by "creating environment variable called ANDROID_SDK_HOME like you did before with .temp and set its value to your desirec location like "E:\Android". You can move your previous .android folder in that directory too if you want to save previous data :)

Comment: If I answered this right, checking this answer as accepted will help me as well. :)

Comment: Yes, I guess I was referring to the AVD. Thank you so much for your help and patience, I am quite new to this and you pointed me in the right directions. I must add, you also helped me understand what questions I should ask. For anyone else who has this issue, you can check the following answers as well. I would suggest to read them all and use the instructions to the letter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109473/moving-default-avd-configuration-folder-android

Comment: I am happy to help :)