# Android Studio ignores ANDROID_AVD_HOME

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I moved all `~/.android/avd/*` contents to the new directory and set the env variable (in `~/.bash_profile`):

```
$ echo $ANDROID_AVD_HOME
/Volumes/VMs/avd/
```

```
$ ls $ANDROID_AVD_HOME
Nexus_S_API_28.avd      Pixel_3_API_23_x86.avd      Pixel_3_API_28_x86.avd      Pixel_3a_x86_64_API_29.avd  SGS9_Plus_API_28.avd
Nexus_S_API_28.ini      Pixel_3_API_23_x86.ini      Pixel_3_API_28_x86.ini      Pixel_3a_x86_64_API_29.ini  SGS9_Plus_API_28.ini
```

And restarted Android Studio, but AVD Manager does not see these images.

New emulators are also created in the old directory:

```
$ ls ~/.android/avd/
Pixel_3a_XL_API_29.avd  Pixel_3a_XL_API_29.ini
```

Android Studio 3.5.2, macOS 10.13.6.

What's wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving default AVD configuration folder (.android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109473/moving-default-avd-configuration-folder-android)

Comment: @kandroidj it suggests moving entire `.android` directory, but I want to move only `.android/avd`. That should be possible with setting  ANDROID_AVD_HOME env var (according to docs), but does not work.

Comment: This is so annoying. I changed every single variable (ANDROID_AVD_HOME, ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME), but AVD Manager still uses ~/.android/avd folder. Though `emulator -list-avds` shows the emulator.

Comment: I ended up just not using AVD Manager at all. `emulator` command works fine and doesn't ignore envvars. Sent an issue as well.

Comment: just use sim link `ln -s /Volumes/VMs/avd ~/.android/avd `