# Changing the AVDs / Emulator default path not working in windows

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Because of my windows "C partition" disk is low space I decided to move AVDs and all emulators devices with different api's that I creadted to my external HDD.

I followed the solutions in **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3109473/4205927)** and **[the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46976475/4205927)** but no one is solved the problem,

I changed **ANDROID_SDK_HOME** to **"E:\ .android"**

and changed **ANDROID_AVD_HOME** to **E:\ .android\avd**

then I changed the ini files in each device path to new one for example 
 **path=E:\ .android\avd\Pixel_4_XL_API_30.avd**

[image: example of avd conf file]

then after I restartd the device and cleared cached in AS I got no device

[image]

also I tried to change **ANDROID_USER_HOME** and **ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME**, currently I have this three vars in windows enviroment

[image]

it's look like android studio ignores this variables and forced set android avd to it's defualt path **C:\Users<USERNAME>.android\ or ~/.android/**