# problem creating Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've just installed Eclipse and am trying to create my first Emulator. The problem is that I have a partioned drive and my C drive only has 750Mb left, so I installed Eclipse on my D drive which has over 10Gb. My workspace is also on the D drive but when I try to create an emulator virtual device it defaults to c:\documants and settings... when I try to change it to a new folder in my workspace I get an error saying 'Not a valid keystore path'. How can I get around this?

Comment: Hi, do you use your absolute path of your workspace?

Comment: Yes, I path it to a folder of my D drive but it seems to be looking for some sort of file.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? Try searching for a solution based on that.

Answer (score 1):

This question is rather old, so you may have already fixed your issue. For others reading this, look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4648123/1993898

I used his example to create an environment variable, changing the directory to one on my D:\ drive, in order to cause the AVD to be stored there, rather than my C:\ drive.

You can right-click "My Computer" and hit "r" or select properties, to open the System page, then hit "Advanced system settings" from the left hand side, and the "Environment Variables" button from the bottom of the resulting dialog.

Then just hit the "New..." button in the upper section, enter "ANDROID_SDK_HOME" for the Name field, and enter your preferred path in the Value field.

Your ".android" folder will now be located in the directory you entered, which holds the "avd" folder among other data. I found this very useful to store my working files on a separate drive, preventing loss of information in the event that my system drive is damaged or wiped.