# How do I change the default location of an Android AVD?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I noticed today that when I created my first AVD

```
android create avd --target 2 --name my_avd
```

that the default location was not in my Eclipse or SDK homes but rather in c:\Documents and Settings\username.android\avd

How can I edit this path???  The last thing I want is my AVD in a location like that.  Code is shared between Linux and Windows based developers and opening the project (because of settings in Run | Run Configurations | Target) causes errors because the AVD(s) cannot be found.

Again, how can I edit where an AVD is stored?  Windows | Preferences | Android doesn't have anything either.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please look this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841766/possible-to-change-where-android-virtual-devices-are-saved).