# Android virtual device manager base location settings

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have installed eclipse and have set up Android SDK,all the required folders r in a secondary drive (G:).After that when m starting Android virtual device manager its location is showing my C: drive.Will it cause any problem when m running Android programs.
And how can I change the drive location to G: in AVD ??

Answer (score 0):

Won't cause any problems, but you can change the location if desired: [Possible to change where Android Virtual Devices are saved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841766/possible-to-change-where-android-virtual-devices-are-saved)