# change the Android virtual Device HDD location

Tags: android, eclipse

How can change the **Android virtual device locate** using **Eclipse**?
when i create a new AVD that file store in default location(C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME.android\avd ) so now i want to change other place.

Comment: Your question is too generic, please specify more. You can manage AVDs with the SDK Manager (that you can oper from Eclipse if you want..) and you can manually find the AVDs on your HDD at `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\.android\avd`

Comment: Look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841766/possible-to-change-where-android-virtual-devices-are-saved

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The AVD manager doesn't provide an option for changing your AVD's location. I'm not sure if there's a way for changing the default path. However you can manually change your AVD's location via command line.

On the cmd line, navigate to your sdk directory's tools folder and then fire up the android tool.
Should look something like..

```
C:\android-sdk\tools> android move avd -n your_avd -p c:\new\path\here
```

[Moving AVDs via cmdline](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html#moving)

And don't forget that you're new path should not contain spaces.

Comment: An answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841766/possible-to-change-where-android-virtual-devices-are-saved

Answer (score 0):

can you please specify more , if you want to change the target device for running your application then you can do  by going in eclipse upper browser u will find "android like image with and down arrow " click that one and you will find of the device if you have created previous and there are options to edit , new etc

Answer (score 0):

1. Place your AVD [folder [xxx.avd]] anywhere you wish to.
2. Now open the avd's ini file and correct the path of the avd there with  the current location.
3. AVD Manager locates AVDs from a default location. [which you can check in the AVD manager].
4. Copy the edited ini file to this location.

and you are all set to go. Hope this helps you!!