# 'Create new Android Virtual Device (AVD)' hangs after I click 'ok'

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

Here is where it hangs:

[image]

I have installed the Android 4.0 API 14 ARM EABI v7a system image (along with everything else under 'Android 4.0 (API14)), this seems to be the most common problem but it's not the one that's causing my issues it seems.

After a while it stops being hung but it doesn't add the virtual device either.

Comment: in windows C:\Users\admin\.android\avd this is the path where AVD are created and stored and delete those and create a new one ... try it ...it works for me

Answer (score 1):

try using "adb kill-server" and then "adb start-server" commands on command prompt from the path where your platform tools are available

 e.g. ..\Android\android-sdk_r21-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, the default directory to which the avd's were being created was my main hard drive which is a fairly tiny ssd, it simply didn't have the room to store the avd.

I followed this: [Possible to change where Android Virtual Devices are saved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841766/possible-to-change-where-android-virtual-devices-are-saved) to change the default directory to make actual work drive and that fixed it.