# AVD failing to run on Android Studios

Tags: android, installation, android-emulator

I just started using Android Studios (used to use Eclipse) and I haven't been able to run my first program. A couple of answers I checked haven't been helpful. I change RAM to 748MB. Then I noticed this error:

```
NAND: could not write file C:\Users\Kbluue\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMP43A5.tmp, No space left on device
```

Seeing as my C:\ was crowded I tried changing the directory into the D:\ drive and this question seemed to answer that: [Possible to change where Android Virtual Devices are saved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841766/possible-to-change-where-android-virtual-devices-are-saved). Only the top answer didn't help. Here's the new error

```
D:\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_S_API_21 -netspeed full -netdelay none

Note: The environment variable $ANDROID_SDK_HOME is set, and the emulator uses that variable to locate AVDs.
This may result in the emulator failing to start if it cannot find the AVDs in the folder pointed to by the
given environment variable.
ANDROID_SDK_HOME=D:\Users\Kbluue

NAND: could not write file C:\Users\Kbluue\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMP43A5.tmp, No space left on device
```

Another answer said something about a tools directory which I unluckily couldn’t find in my studios.

What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by deleting files from users/.AndroidStudio/tmp and also getting more space on C , where Android Studio was installed.(I had just 500 Mb free )

Comment: i dont have /tmp in my .androidStudio folder, just /config and /system. is there any other options. I would revert to eclipse but news around here is that the support has been stopped.

Comment: no , don t go to eclipse again ... at a moment you will have  to migrate and better now than later . try to reinstall in a place where is more free space . Do you have ssd ? try to install android studio on different partition