# debug Android app using Visual Studio 2015 Cordova on a VMware and have debug.keystore not found error

Tags: android, cordova, debugging, batch-file, vmware

The build is OK until it's asking for a debug key. Here is part of the output log:

```
[apkbuilder] Creating MainActivity-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...
1>MDAVSCLI : [apkbuilder] keytool error : java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\vmware-host\Shared Folders\.android\debug.keystore (The system cannot find the path specified)
1>  [apkbuilder] Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
1>  Command finished with error code 1: C:\FirstApp\FirstApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug
1>ERROR building one of the platforms : error : C:\FirstApp\FirstApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 1
1>  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
1>MDAVSCLI : error : C:\FirstApp\FirstApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 1
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm running a Windows 8.1 on mac Yosemite using VMware. Seems like it's trying to look for the debug key in share folder and couldn't find it. I'm clueless how I can fix this problem.

I've checked the environment variables, ADT_HOME, ANT_HOME, GIT_HOME, JAVA_HOME and they all point to the correct locations.

%JAVA_HOME%\bin is also added to the system environment PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem is that I can't create folder under \vmware-host\Shared Folders. This also gave me hard time when running Android SDK Manager to fetch Android repository because the Manifest Cache directory points to \vmware-host\Shared Folders too.

The solution is to add a new environment variable.
Variable name: ANDROID_SDK_HOME
Variable value: C:\Users>User Name<

This is the post that helps a lot. [Possible to change where Android Virtual Devices are saved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841766/possible-to-change-where-android-virtual-devices-are-saved)

Don't forget to restart the computer after the change.