# In Android Studio, Create AVD at New Path (As my C drive is full)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I dont have Space in my C Drive, Hence I want to Create AVD in Android Studio in Another Drive. How can I Change setting of AVD Manager, So All my New AVDs are created at New Path-Directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to change where Android Virtual Devices are saved?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841766/possible-to-change-where-android-virtual-devices-are-saved)

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered before, according to [@wloescher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355652/wloescher):

Add a new user environment variable (Windows 7):

1. Start Menu > Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings (on
   the left) > Environment Variables
2. Add a new user variable (at the top) that points your home user
   directory:

> ```
> Variable name: ANDROID_SDK_HOME Variable value: a path to
> a directory of your choice AVD Manager will use this directory to
> save its .android directory into it.
> ```

[Original post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841766/possible-to-change-where-android-virtual-devices-are-saved)

If you are on a Linux system: [How to set up environment variables on Linux.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps)

If you are on a Mac: [How to set up environment variables on Mac.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion)