# Change Visual Studio Emulator for Android vhd install path

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, hyper-v

Is it possible to change the default path that the VS emulator is storing the *.vhd* files? By default it's set to store them under my **%LOCALAPPDATA%** folder, but that's on my C drive and I'm running out of space on C.

How can I set it to store them in **D:\emulators**?

Comment: You can find answer for similar question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841766/possible-to-change-where-android-virtual-devices-are-saved

Answer (score 4):

@Ionian316

1/ Open regedit.

2/ Go to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Configuration\

3/ Find file ***UserConfigurationPath***

4/ Input your path in here:

Default path is: **%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android**

New path example: **D:\VisualStudioEmulator\Android**

Of course, you should copy from default path to new path for not be error.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 1**

There is a solution pointed in VS Emulator for Android troubleshooting ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx#Visual-Studio-gets-stuck-trying-to-deploy-the-app-to-the-emulator-or-the-emulator-does-not-appear-as-a-debug-target-in-other-IDEs)):

1. Open **Registry** Editor by selecting Run from the Start buttons context menu, typing regedit in the dialog box, and choosing OK.
2. Navigate to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Android SDK Tools** in the folder tree on the left.
3. Modify the Path registry variable to match the path to your Android SDK.

However, **this solution seems out-of-date** for current available VS Emu 4 Android versions. I can not find the registry folder in the tree.

**EDIT 2**

Here is a simple way to do, by which I managed to change the root Path of vhd.

**Situation 1: Already installed**

1. Rename folder **`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\`** to something else, for backup.
2. Create folder **`D:\emulators`**.
3. Open **cmd command-line**, type in **`MKLINK /J %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\ D:\emulators`**, press Enter.
4. After junction made, move everything in backuped vhd folder to **`D:\emulators`**.
5. You've done.

**Situation 2: Not installed yet**

1. The steps are similar to those in **Situation 1**, but you do not need to rename for backup, nor move the backuped stuff to **`D:\emulators`**.
2. You just need to make the junction, and then install VSEmu4Android.

**EDIT 3**

**NOTE:**

For proper usage of vhd's in Hyper-V (which is used by VSEmu4Android), your **`D:\emulators`** folder and files inside should not be compressed.