# Android Virtual Device/ Android Emulator - Decryption Unsuccessful

Tags: android, android-studio, encryption, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I just installed Android Studio, and I am very new with this program.

So when I run the Android Emulator it says: "To Start Android, enter your password", although I have never set a password. When I just enter a word with 4 letters it says "The Password you entered is correct, but unfortunately your data is corrupt".

After that, I have to Reset the Phone, but when I do that the same menu with "To Start Android, enter your password" appears.

Maybe it is just an easy mistake, but as I said I am new with this. I also did some research on the internet but I did not find anything useful.

this is the 2 images that it showe me:

1)[image: the first image]
2) [image: the seconde image]

and after i clicked on reset phone, nothing happened.

I would be very glad if someone has an answer for this.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem :s

Comment: for me, I encoutered this problem when entering wrong pw

Answer (score 35):

This is a late response, but thought this simple fix might help anyone else who comes across this problem in the future.  What worked for me is the following:

In VS2017 ==> Tools ==> Android ==> Select: Android Device Manager

In the Android Device Manager window, you'll see your Android Emulator.

1. Make sure the far right column contains the button "Start" (if "Stop" appears, click "Stop")
2. Right Click the device, and select the "Factory Reset" option in the menu.

Your emulator should now be working.  Good luck.

Comment: Worked in VS 2019 too. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

open AVD and right click on the emulator choose ->Wipe data option.

Answer (score 4):

Check that your avd folder path doesn't include national symbols (in my case it looked like C:\Users\Пользователь\.android).

After I changed this path everything is working.
See this post of how to change path:
[Possible to change where Android Virtual Devices are saved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841766/possible-to-change-where-android-virtual-devices-are-saved)

Answer (score 2):

Check out "Viewing and managing your Avds" part. Try wiping data of your emulator or create a new emulator for yourself.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

Answer (score 1):

Change the Android version. I was creating an emulator with Oreo 8.1 and got stuck in with the same issue.
I created another with Marshmallows 6.0 and no more asking for password.
Then if you are using Oreo 8.1 try with antoher.

Answer (score 0):

I created a virtual device, and after, I had to reinstall the emulator. 
When I booted the virtual device, I got this issue. 
I deleted it and made a new one, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just go the AVD Manager and Wipe Data. The problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I followed after my device corrupted.

- Close your emulator
- Open AVD manager, right click on your device and click "Cold Boot Now" button.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a very Late Answer. But you can't create a x64 Virtual Device on x64 System. Your device needs to be x86.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "you can't create an x64 virtual device on an x86 system"?

Comment: That too. But x64 on a x64 can't be created either. Only In case if your CPU allows Hardware Virtaulization (and is enabled in BIOS), then you can.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your field, but surely creating an x86 VM on an x64 system is easier than an x86 VM on an x64 system? And likewise, are you saying you can **only** create an x64 VM on an x86 system? That sounds back-to-front. Could you provide some documentation for this? I'd be interested to read into why that is.

Answer (score 0):

Just a warning to anyone getting this error on an emulator instance that was working and you cold booted or something. I got this error and just stopped and cold booted again and it was gone! So try that first before wiping your emulator instance unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the device in the Device Manager and created a new  one with a higher OS version (Oreo -> Pie).  The error disappeared.   Did not find the real reason yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's very nearly 2024 and this is still happening. The fix for me combined a couple of other answers.

I was trying to simulate a Pixel 2 on Android 8.1. I wanted it to be 64-bit (like the real device is) but it gave me the error the original question encountered. Only after I switched it down to 32-bit (x86) and then ALSO enabled Google API and Google Play Store (these options are disabled in 64-bit mode for some reason) did it start up properly (it's possible only one of either of those options is needed, but I don't care because it's working now).