# App keeps crashing when I run it in the emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

Everytime I click run, firstly it takes forever building and displaying and then it comes up with this message:

[Here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwabB.png) (apologies for the blurry image)

I also get these errors in my event log when I close my emulator:

**19:56 Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe:**

**19:56 Emulator: Unable to open** **C:\Users\talha.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_27_1.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin: Permission denied**

Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Comment: Permission Denied on a folder means the user running the emmulator doesn't have permission for using the mentioned folder. You have to run it with a user that has permission over that folder, or have an administrator give permissions to your user to use that folder. I guess that the permission needed would be read, write, and execute.

Comment: Would it change if I use a different virtual device?

Comment: I think there are some alternatives here you can explore https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841766/possible-to-change-where-android-virtual-devices-are-saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to C:\Android.android\avd\MyNexus5API27.avd\data\misc, make right click on pstore, pick Properties and uncheck box Only for reading (Title may be a little different).

Comment: I tried this but it won't save my changes and still shows as 'read only', which results in my app continuing to crash

Comment: delete the lock file in this route  C:\Users*your user*.android\avd/MyNexus5API27.avd/*.lock

Comment: I don't see a '.lock' or anything similar to that in this route, could you possibly show me a screenshot of how this is supposed to look please?

Comment: You can solv it by recreating the AVD from scratch.
use Android studio and delete the AVD first
delete the Folders according to your AVD name example-Nexus_5X_API_27